# Build Cocoa application Bundle with private dylib/framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, frameworks, build

I use xcode 4 to build a cocoa application with a private dylib/framework.

In my development Mac, I put the dylib in the /usr/local/lib directory, and drag it into the project.

The app is compiled and runs perfect on my computer.

To distribute this app to the other Mac, I create a copy Files building phase, and say "copy that dylib to Frameworks directory".

The application is built successfully, and I indeed see the dylib is copied to the Frameworks directory in the app bundle.

The problem is when I run this app in another regular Mac, which does not have this dylib installed. I get an error saying:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/mylib.dylib
```

Comment: Are you building the library from source, or did you get it from somewhere already built?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that you copy the framework into the app bundle, so it is available at a location like:

```
 <you_app_path>/Contents/Frameworks
```

but you try to load it from `/usr/local/lib` where it is not available on you deployment machine. From [Apple Framework Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html):

> To embed a framework in an application, there are several steps you must take:
>
> You must configure the build phases of your application target to put the framework in the correct location.
>
> You must configure the framework target’s installation directory, which tells the framework where it will live.
>
> You must configure the application target so that it references the framework in its installation directory.

Now, you say that the build phase is ok; I assume also that you sent the application target build setting correctly. What is left is configuring the framework target’s installation directory.

If you did not build the framework yourself, you should be able to fix this by changing the framework install path so that it is defined relative to the loader (your app), to something like: `@loader_path/../Frameworks/` (or `@executable_path/../Frameworks`). You can do that by means of [install_name_tool](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html).

If you are compiling on your own the private framework, you can define its install location in Xcode build settings.

Comment: Yes. this method works. At least I can let the application load the private framework in the deployment machine. But another error appears. The private framework links several library (/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib libcurl, ... etc).

I use otool to check the library path and it shows 

/usr/lib/lib***

My problem is how the set the path of these libs?

Comment: With dylibs you can use install_name_tool and specify @loader_path/../Frameworks/ (not executable_path).