# Translating command line options into Xcode IDE

Tags: xcode, unix, linker

I am a new user to both Unix and Xcode, so I apologize if this question is already discussed elsewhere.
I am trying to use a third party algorithm database (NAG C Library) on my macbook, and in their user's manual I saw the following lines:

```
gcc driver.c -I[INSTALL_DIR]/include [INSTALL_DIR]/lib/libnagc_vl.dylib -framework vecLib -lpthread -lm
```

I understand that `-I[INSTALL_DIR]/include` is adding the directory into my header search path, but I have no idea what `[INSTALL_DIR]/lib/libnagc_vl.dylib` is doing since it doesn't seem to be an option. Also, what does `-framework` mean here?

Perhaps the most important question is how I can implement these options when I am trying to build the program in Xcode IDE? Sorry if this seems a lot of questions to answer... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that libnagc_vl.dylib in your "NAG C Library"; dylib means: "dynamic (or sharable) library" ( versus .a that is the self-contained library )

while the option

> -framework framework

Links the executable being built against the listed framework. For example, you might add -framework vecLib to include support for vector math.

To get a full documentation of the compiler, in *terminal* you can type:

```
man gcc
```

In the answer of "[Build Cocoa application Bundle with private dylib/framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102609/build-cocoa-application-bundle-with-private-dylib-framework)" are enumerated the steps required to embed a framework in an application

Then to implement this options when you build the program you have to learn about **"targets"**. A target contains the instructions for building a finished product from a set of files in your project; a way to learn this is from the help menu of Xcode type: **target** and **gcc**

These documents also could be of interest:

- [Compiling Your Code in OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html)
- [Creating a Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html)