# Install and distribute dylib with program

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dylib

I purchased a chilkat FTP2 license, and need to replace my existing code (taken from the Apple's [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html)) with the one provided by this library.

How do I properly install it on my Mac and set my project up to distribute it with my App? Does every user need to install it on his Mac by himself or can it be packed with the App?

Every tutorial I found is quite complicated, I would need something simple as I am new to Xcode and Objective-C

EDIT:

- Distribution is as downloadable App over my webpage.
- Its for Mac OS X.

Comment: There is a place where you can stick the .dylib in the .app you distribute. I believe it goes in Content/Frameworks. You might have to check the dylibs install paths perhaps. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102609/build-cocoa-application-bundle-with-private-dylib-framework for more about it. See http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_objc.asp for the official info on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not distribute non-Apple dynamic libraries with iOS apps on the app store.

The reason every tutorial you find is complicated is because the only way to get Xcode to actually build an iOS app with a dynamic library involves some hacks and workarounds.

Comment: I dont want to distribute it on the Apps store. My app is distributed as download on my site.